# Multiple Dynamically Added Fields at Same Time

Tags: javascript, mysql, dynamic, input

I have these fields. I want to add this same set of fields dynamically. I can do one at a time but cannot seem to make all fields repeat. I am using to build an in house purchase order and inventory management system and this is the last part missing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

$(function(){

$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {

var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);

$(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {

    $('.multi-field:first-child',              

 $wrapper).clone(true) .appendTo($wrapper).find

   ('input').val('').focus();

  });

  $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {

   if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)

    $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();

   });

   });

   });//]]>  

</script>


<form role="form" action="test2.php" method="POST">

<label>Stuff</label>

<div class="multi-field-wrapper">

  <div class="multi-fields">

  <div class="multi-field">

      <?php mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "deadman1") or               

     die("Connection Failed"); mysql_select_db("inv")or

    die("Connection Failed"); $query = "SELECT * FROM po order by id 

  desc limit 1"; $result = mysql_query($query); ?>

    <select name="po">

    <?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?> 

   <option value="<?php echo $line['ID'];?>

    "> <?php echo $line['ID'];?>

  </option>   <?php } ?>

 </select>
      <input type="text" name="vendor">

      <input type="text" name="part">

      <input type="text" name="qty">

      <input type="text" name="min">

      <button type="button" class="remove-field">Remove</button>

     </div>

    </div>

   <button type="button" class="add-field">Add field</button>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>

 <center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="PURCHASE">
   </center>
   </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: What do you mean dynamically? Are you trying to add these input fields to a page using JavaScript when you click a button?

Comment: i have to input into a mysql database its for a purchase order deal but i got the answer ill post a link to page soon.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aaki/hMJEy/1/  with a little tweeking buy adding the required amount of fields and nameing them worked beautifully